# How to let onclick disappear after clicking on something else

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

I am just working on my new webspace and I have a small problem.
I know have to input tags with an onclick function

```
<script>
function mark( el ) {
    el.style.borderBottom= "3px solid white";
  }
</script>
```

When I click on the first input the border appears as I want but when I click on the other input the border of the first input tag is still there.
So how can I let the function only work when it's only clicked on the input tag itself and not when another input is clicked as well

Thanking you in anticipation

Comment: You can use CSS `focus` selector to achieve this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use CSS's `:focus` pseudo class:

```css
input:focus {
    border-bottom:3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
```

[MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus)

Answer (score 1):

Before you add style to this specific element you can remove style of all inputs or something like this:

```
function mark( el ) {
    var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(var i =0;input.length>i;i++){
       input[i].removeAttribute("style");
    }
    el.style.borderBottom= "3px solid white";
}
```

Comment: If you have multiple inputs, you have to add a loop

Comment: You're right my bad, using to much Jquery :-), your answer is a better way anyways

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use CSS Focus selector. `input:focus`

```css
input:focus {
    background-color: yellow;
 border-bottom:3px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div><input type="text"></div>
<br/>
<div><input type="text"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do.  First, create a mark and an unmark functions. Then trigger the mark function at "onmousedown" and unmark at "onmouseup" event. Therefore, this border will only be shown when you have the mouse button pressed.

```
<script>
function mark( el ) {
    el.style.borderBottom= "3px solid white";
  }

function unmark( el ) {
    el.style.borderBottom= "none";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I could show you how to set the events too,  if you add the HTML code